# How to add out of stock product to cart programmatically in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, addtocart, quote, out-of-stock

I'm using Magento v2.3, I want to add out of stock products to cart **without changing any configuration from backend**.

I'm using following function to add product to cart

```
addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo)
```

from following class

> Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart

But it checks for saleable quantity.

Is there any way to ignore saleable check and add out of stock products to cart?

Comment: any specific reason instead of using default feature you want to create an extra feature which will slow down checkout?

Comment: yes, one of my feature strictly depends on default functionality of decreasing the quantity when order is placed and no add to cart when quantity is zero, so can't change that. Feature mentioned in question will work for restricted users, so it doesn't make difference if it slow down a little.

Comment: I think better to look into these settings once: Set System->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Backorders=Allow Qty Below 0.
Set System->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Stock Options->Display Out of Stock Products=Yes. These settings will though decrease an item on sale, but will show add to cart button even an item is 0 or <0.

Comment: share full code please

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add out of stock products to cart without changing any configuration from the backend then  you have added enable super mode of the product during add to card

```
    $productInfo->setIsSuperMode(true) ; 

...->addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, I didn't test yet. I hope it helps.

1. We can set session variable **skip_is_saleable==true** before your add product logic
2. Then override the **public function isSaleable()** function by **di.xml** and check the above session variable
3. If you found **skip_is_saleable==true**, always return true in **isSaleable** function. Otherwise, leave it as a core step in **isSaleable** so that it does not affect the default flow.
4. Finally, clear the session variable **skip_is_saleable**